# Excel VBA add to a different tab based on time

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm going to a workshop for school and this workshop has several classes at the same time, and I have a VBA code to where if I select Yes to one of those classes, then the other cells will automatically fill with no and add a strikethrough.

[image]

Example 1 shows that Workshop 1 was selected, therefore, the other 2 workshops at the same time should be "No" and a strikethrough.

I have the code for this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range

Endrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Range("A1:A" & Endrow)
  If c.Value = "No" Then
     c.EntireRow.Font.strikethrough = True
  Else
     c.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
     c.EntireRow.Font.strikethrough = False
  End If
Next
   
End Sub
```

How can I implement this to where it adds it to a 'calendar' tab based on time? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You could research the `Worksheet.Change` event.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me for the first part. I've added the new code. Now, my question is how can I implement it to where if it's Yes on "A2", and No on the other 8am classes(A2: "Yes", A3-A4: "No"), to where it will copy/paste that value that's Yes to another tab called schedule at exactly that same time at 8:00am?